# Break (or brake) a loop in this specific code - Python

Tags: python, while-loop, break

I was trying to create a "end" variable, that should break (or brake) but it clearly didn't work.

The question from my homework:

Modify the program above to give the user only 5 guesses. If there are more than 5 guesses, the user should get the following message: (in code)

The first code was working perfect, but in this one, the `while` loop just repeats.

```
# Welcome message
print("Welcome to the Magic Ball!")

# The magic number
answer = 7

# Prepares "end" variable
end = False

# Take guess
guess = int(input("\nYour guess: "))

# While loop

# While guess NOT EQUAL to ANSWER, re-ask
# And add whever too high or too low
# Used a boolean to tell the program when to stop the loop
while guess != answer or end == True:
    for guess in range(1, 5, +1): # For loops limits ammount of guesses
        guess = int(input("\nYour guess: "))
    if guess > answer:
        print("\nToo high")
    elif guess < answer:
        print("\nToo low")
    # If still not completed, print "max chances"
    print("You have gotten to your maximum answers")
    # This ends the loop so it stops going around
    end = True

# If loop passed, tell the user it's correct
# After printing "max chances", the Python will print this out,
# So make sure the answers match
if guess == answer:
    print("\nWell done")
```

Comment: Look very closely at the `while guess != answer or end == True` condition again.
(And this isn't your problem, but just a tip, don't use the equality operators like == to compare booleans. Just test them bare, like `while end`.)

Comment: @grayshirt But still, the loop continues

Comment: It's just a logic error. Break down what that condition tests, when it will pass and when it will fail and see how it differs from what you intend.

Comment: On the first guess (value) entered by the user, the value of "end" will be True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is your logic in the while loop is wrong.

It should be:

```
while guess != answer and not end:
```

The next problem is that your `for` loop is looping through asking for 4 answers, but it never prints the hints, as the indentation of those print statements is too low.

Also, you probably don't want a for loop inside the while loop at all, just pick one type of loop or the other.  If you go with the while loop, you'll need a counter, to keep track of the number of guesses.

One other glaring issue, is that you are using `guess` as your for loop iterator, but then you are resetting it with the user's input.  This is very bad!

Here is the code using a for loop, which is probably the best type of loop to use, since it eliminates the need to increment the counter variable as in a while loop.

```
# Welcome message
print("Welcome to the Magic Ball!")

# The magic number
answer = 7

for _ in range(5):
    guess = int(input("\nYour guess: "))
    if guess == answer:
        break
    elif guess > answer:
        print("Too high")
    elif guess < answer:
        print("Too low")
if guess == answer:
    print("Well done!")
else:
    print("You have used all your guesses")
print("The answer was {}".format(answer))
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got a for loop inside a while loop, and that's redundant. You should pick one or the other.  If you want to stop looping if the correct answer is guessed, you just need to move your if statement (currently at the very end) inside the loop.

Also, there's no need for the "+1" in your range(), because 1 is the default.

Comment: What if I wanted to include on inside the other?

Comment: Does your assignment require you to do that for some reason?  Otherwise there's no point to it.

Comment: Don't think it requires, but at the moment I'm studying Python for my GCSE so like, I have to show I can do my best, although I'm trying to do the impossible

Answer (score 0):

You're using two loops instead of just one - either go with only the for loop, or actually make use of you while loop.

Here's one possibility (using just the while loop, also I didn't test this):

```
# While guess NOT EQUAL to ANSWER, re-ask
# And add whever too high or too low
# Used a boolean to tell the program when to stop the loop
tries = 1
while (not guess == answer) and (not tries == 5):
    guess = int(input("\nYour guess: "))
    if guess > answer:
        print("\nToo high")
    elif guess < answer:
        print("\nToo low")
    else:
        tries += 1
    if tries == 5:
        print("You have gotten to your maximum answers")
```